# PBKDF2 interoperability: PHP and C#

Tags: c#, php, pbkdf2

I'm trying to sign up users through a PHP webapp and validate them with C# under .net core 7. I'm having difficulty getting the hashes to match between the front and back ends. I encode the password hash in PHP like this:

```
   $salt = bin2hex(random_bytes(64));
   $binPassword = hash_pbkdf2("sha512", "test", $salt, 1000, 64,true);
   $hashedPassword = bin2hex($binPassword);
```

Then $salt and $hashedPassword go into a database which I retrieve from my C# backend. Then

```
        byte[] saltBytes = hex2bin(salt);
        var pbkdf2 = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(
            "test",
            saltBytes,
            1000,
            HashAlgorithmName.SHA512);
        var hashBytes = pbkdf2.GetBytes(64);
        var myHash = bin2hex(hashBytes);
        Console.WriteLine($"myHash={myHash}");
        Console.WriteLine($"hashedPassword={hashedPassword}");
```

The bin2hex() and hex2bin() routines in C# are as follows:

```
    static string bin2hex(byte[] bytes)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (byte b in bytes)
        {
            var hex = b.ToString("x2");
            sb.Append(hex);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
    static byte[] hex2bin(string hexdata)
    {
        if (hexdata == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("hexdata");
        if (hexdata.Length % 2 != 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("hexdata should have even length");

        byte[] bytes = new byte[hexdata.Length / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < hexdata.Length; i += 2)
            bytes[i / 2] = (byte) (HexValue(hexdata[i]) * 0x10
                                   + HexValue(hexdata[i + 1]));
        return bytes;
    }

    static int HexValue(char c)
    {
        int ch = (int) c;
        if (ch >= (int) '0' && ch <= (int) '9')
            return ch - (int) '0';
        if (ch >= (int) 'a' && ch <= (int) 'f')
            return ch - (int) 'a' + 10;
        if (ch >= (int) 'A' && ch <= (int) 'F')
            return ch - (int) 'A' + 10;
        throw new ArgumentException("Not a hexadecimal digit.");
    }
```

Im expecting the hashes to match. My latest run of the backend produces this:

```
myHash=ef3860d356217f9c69d6aea4647ef58bd6dc64ca2559699ca56721b606188508456f3939634f78ffb63a0b79c1e696985705ff5e972e13c8def535a732e73cbf
hashedPassword=7a2dcfb5217198d8b07dd6ded7cf02b1bb7e4c1017a52f2c611b28a053c1d46c5db4f9355e05f5212984adf33465e0e3d7c11ecb2385f47a26e87c30b0a9ba99
```

The hashes don't match.

Comment: In both codes a different salt is used. The PHP code applies the hex encoded salt `bin2hex(random_bytes(64))` in the key derivation, while in C# the raw salt `hex2bin(salt)` is used. By the way .NET supports hex encoding / decoding with `Convert.ToHexString()`/`Convert.FromHexString`.

Comment: The issue seems to be more of a typo. The fix should be to use the raw salt in the PHP code for key derivation and to hex encode the salt only for export, which is then to be hex decoded on the C# side.

Comment: This fixed the problem. Thanks for the quick response!

$salt = random_bytes(64);
$dbsalt = bin2hex($salt);